# Как правильно делать запросы в операторе flatMap?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Я получаю с сервера список чатов(переписок). Их запихиваю в класс `ChatsModel`. И в этом классе имеется `userId`, то есть в каждом чате имеется `id` того пользователя. Других информации о пользователе нет.И еще есть одно поле для данных о пользователе типа `UserMessagesResponse`.

Так вот для начала этот `userMessagesResponse` равен `null`.

После того как я получил список чатов и `userId`, я должен отправить другой запрос для получения информации о пользователе. Делаю я это таким образом:

```
private void loadChatsFromNetwork(int count, AccessDataModel accessDataModel) {
    String accessToken = accessDataModel.getAccessToken();

    Flowable<ChatsModel> chatsModelSingle = getChatsApi().getChats(count, accessToken, Constants.api_version)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(chatsModel -> {
                RealmList<Item> items = chatsModel.getResponse().getItems();
                StringBuilder userIds = new StringBuilder();

                for (Item item : items) {
                    userIds.append(item.getMessage().getUserId()).append(",");
                }

                return loadUsersById(userIds, chatsModel);
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    chatsModelSingle.subscribe(chatsModel -> {
                Log.d(TAG, chatsModel.getResponse().getItems().first().getMessage().getMessagesUserItem().getFirstName());
                chatsRepository.updateChatsData(chatsModel);
                iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsSuccess(chatsModel);
            },
            throwable -> {
                iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsError(throwable.getMessage());
                Log.d(TAG, "onError() " + throwable.getMessage());
            });
}

private ChatsModel loadUsersById(StringBuilder userIds, ChatsModel chatsModel) {

    MyApplication.getChatsApi().getUsersByChats(userIds.toString(), "photo_100")
            .subscribe(messagesUser -> {

                RealmList<Item> item = chatsModel.getResponse().getItems();

                for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
                    Message message = item.get(i).getMessage();

                    RealmList<UserMessagesResponse> messagesUserItemList = messagesUser.getUserMessagesResponse();
                    for (UserMessagesResponse messagesResponse : messagesUserItemList) {
                        if (messagesResponse.getUid().equals(message.getUserId())) {
                            message.setMessagesUserItem(messagesResponse);
                            chatsModel.getResponse().getItems().get(i).setMessage(message);
                        }
                    }
                }

            });

    return chatsModel;
}
```

Все эти действия происходят в операторе `flapMap`, так как мне нужно полученную информацию о пользователе запихнуть в поле `userMessagesResponse` класса `ChatsModel`. И в случае успеха отправляю в adapter.

Оба запроса корректно работают. Получаю список `userid`, получаю данные о пользователе.

Проблема в том, после возвращения `chatsModel` в `flatMap`, где `return chatsModel`, дальше ничего не происходит, то есть до подписчика не доходит ничего, точнее подписчик никак не реагирует.

**Вопрос**: Как исправить это и вообще как правильно решать такого рода задачи?

Comment: небольшое замечание. Ваш код довольно сложно читать в силу очень большой вложенности. Попробуйте его декомпозировать. По опыту, после грамотной декомпозиции неявные ошибки начинают сами бросаться в глаза

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Совсем забыл об этом...

Comment: Смотрите, у вас chatsModel наполняется внутри `getUsersByChats` `subscribe`, что, по сути равносильно наполнению в коллбеке. А `return chatsModel` сразу за этой подпиской. Т.е. на момент `return` вызов `getUsersByChats` еще не завершен

Comment: Ой извиняюсь. Я не заметил ваш комментарий и внес изменения.

Comment: Ну суть проблемы не изменилась. Вы делаете `return chatsModel` до того, как отработал `subscribe`. Вы, по сути, этим return'ом убили всю идею ReactiveX. Вам надо из `loadUsersById` возвращать не готовый объект, а `Observable` на него и выше по коду подписываться на него

Comment: Не совсем понял вас. Подписаться в блоке оператора flatMap?

Comment: У вас есть некая конечная точка, где вы используете `chatsModel`, например выводите список сообщений на экран. Вот все, что начинается от момента запроса этих сообщений, вплоть до конечной точки должно идти одним потоком наблюдаемое-наблюдатель. Суть ReactiveX в том и состоит, что строится "конвейер", на вход которому идет сырье, а на выходе готовый продукт, а у вас этот тут и там конвейер перегорожен стенами, упираясь в которые полуфабрикаты сыпятся на пол и вы их руками пытаетесь переложить на тот же конвеер, но уже за стеной

Comment: Аналогия я понял, но таки не понял как исправить/решить свою задачу. Может в ответе напишете обширнее, если можно. Так как я уже который раз сталкиваюсь с такими задачами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если формально, то проблема ваша в том, что вы делаете `return chatsModel` **до** того момента, как выполнится код из `subscribe`, в котором он наполняется.

Если по сути, то ошибка у вас в идеологии. Вы пытаетесь скрестить ежа с ужом. 
Идеология ReactiveX состоит в том, что вы управляете не фиксированными объектами, а потоками данных(событий), причем асинхронно. А у вас получается так: пошел асинхронный поток, вы его тут-же пытаетесь собрать в объект, синхронно причем, и запустить в другой поток.

Распишем ваш поток:

1. Происходит какое-то событие, которое инициирует загрузку чатов
2. Получаем список чатов `List<Chat>`
3. Для каждого чата получаем информацию о пользователе (`getUserInfo`)
4. Делаем с этими чатами какую-то полезную работу (`redrawMyNiceChatsTable`)

Т.е. логика у вас должны быть примерно следующая(отчасти псевдокод):

```
class MyMainClass{
    private ChatsUpdater updater = new ChatsUpdater();
    private List<Chat> chats = new ArrayList<>();

    private void onSomeEventOccured(){
        chats.clear();
        updater.startUpdate()
            .subscribe(
                {chat -> chats.add(chat)},     // onNext
                {redrawMyNiceChatsTable(chats)} // onComplete
            )
    }
}

class ChatsUpdater{
    public Flowable<Chat> startUpdate(){
        return getChats().flatMap(
                    chat -> getUserInfo(chat), 
                    (chat, userInfo) -> {
                        chat.setUserInfo(userInfo);
                        return Observable.just(chat);
                    }
                )
    }

    private Flowable<Chat> getChats(){
        .....
    }

    private Flowable<UserInfo> getUserInfo(Chat chat){
        .....
    }
}
```

**UPD** Ну а если совсем по уму, то, так как у вас жесткая, обязательная,  цепочка `Chat->UserInfo`, вам надо переделать API на стороне сервера, чтобы оно отдавало сразу всю необходимую информацию.

Comment: Сейчас я переделываю все, как вы сказали. Декомпозиция. Суть реактивного подхода походу я понял. А насчет API, то это API VK)

Comment: Все спасибо. Сработало. Я не знал об одном, что можно в `flatMap` использовать два `Function`